# Combine requests with Retrofit2 and RxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to observe two requests with the same `Observer`. My `Observer`:

```
private BaseObserver<LoginResponse> loginObserver = new BaseObserver<LoginResponse>(this) {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        super.onSubscribe(d);
        showLoading(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(LoginResponse response) {
        super.onNext(response);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNext: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        super.onComplete();
        showLoading(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        super.onError(e);
        showLoading(false);
    }
};
```

My request is a login request build with Retrofit2:

```
private void sendRequest(String username, String password) {
    IResourceAPI iResourceAPI = RetrofitClient.createIResourceClient(this);
    iResourceAPI.login(new LoginRequest(username, password))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(loginObserver);
}
```

Now I want to launch 2 or more requests and check the responses one by one in `onNext`, and when the last request is checked execute `onComplete` with my `Observer`. Could anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Combining the two logging response ?

Comment: Use something like - doOnSubscribe, or two observables and combineLatest?

Comment: I want to launch 2 or more request and check the responses one by one in onNext, and when the last request is checked execute onComplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to the [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator:

> You can combine the output of multiple Observables so that they act
>   like a single Observable, by using the Merge operator.

Just modify your request to return an Observable:

```
private Observable<LoginResponse> request(String username, String password) {
    IResourceAPI iResourceAPI = RetrofitClient.createIResourceClient(this);
    iResourceAPI.login(new LoginRequest(username, password))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

Then merge:

```
Observable.merge<LoginResponse>(request(...), request(...))
    .subscribeWith(loginObserver);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator.